# Should the power series solution to $y' = y, y(0) = 1$ be obvious?

Tags: intuition, power-series, growth-rate

## My Understanding:

I would derive the Poisson random variable as follows:

I consider an experiment which consists of a continuum of trials on an interval $[0,t)$. The result of the experiment takes the form of an ordered $n$-tuple of distinct points on the interval. Assuming that every outcome is equally likely, a measure of the sample space is given by a summation for all $n \geq 0$:

$$ I_n = \int_0^{t}  \int_0^{x_{n}} \cdots \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{ x_2 } dx_1 dx_{2} \dots dx_{n-1} dx_{n} = \frac{ t^n } { n! }$$

Put more simply, $t^n$ is scaled by $\frac{1}{n!}$ to avoid over-counting. So, for a Poisson random variable (PRV):

$$P(X = n) = \frac{I_n}{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} I_k }$$

In this light, the probability function of the PRV is highly intuitive and the role of $e^{x}$ is made highly intuitive by its series expansion.

## Question

Given the ODE:

$$y' = y, y(0) = 1$$

Can each term in the solution $y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ be grokked in a similar manner by assigning some physical meaning?

Comment: This is not research level.  However, you might find it helpful to think of this as related to Euler's method for approximating $y(x + \Delta x)$.

Comment: @LSpice, this is algebraically obvious, but not necessarily conceptually obvious in terms of a growth

Comment: *"conceptually obvious in terms of a growth"* And what exactly do these words mean?

Comment: @fedja, it should have said *growth process*, my mistake